# ML .Net algorithm to use to predict correspondence between short text from one set to another short text from another set

Tags: .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I have 2 sets of data, identified by a short text, their name with some minor additions.
Each item from a set has another correspondent item in the other set, based on the name with some minor transformations.

But some items from both sets don't have any link between them. But based on the existing links, I could train a machine learning model to predict and suggest what items to associate to each other from the 2 sets.

So as an input, it should take a name of an item from a set and an entire set of items and try to find the best matching item from that set with the provided item.

But I am stuck figuring out what algorithm to use. Maybe I can just iterate over each item from the set, calculate how similar it's name is with the reference name, and the one with the highest similarity should be used. Maybe they should be ranked according to the similarity.

It would be useful if the similarity algorithm can be used in .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your problem requires an unsupervised algorithm. (I'm assuming you don't have labelled data that identifies matched cases from your sets).

Perhaps a clustering algorithm such as K-Means would help. This is like the 'similarity' algorithm you describe.